# Model object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-models

using Django 1.11 I'm stuck with uuid referencing in my views.
I read through all similar looking questions here, but they either focus on forms or anything else.

**Minimal example**

It's an app called *MegaTest*. It's bound to `/testuuid/`

I have a working index view that generate links to `/testuuid/<uuid>`

If I click on a link on my index page, I get:

```
AttributeError at /testuuid/5a147a14-a9a9-4045-8e79-0ce2e8258a68/
'MegaTest' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**models.py**

```
class MegaTest(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(db_index=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
               editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'testuuid/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'test_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return MegaTest.objects.all()


class MegaTestDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = MegaTest

    def get(self, request, uuid):
        try:
            megatest = MegaTest.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
            return megatest

        except MegaTest.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'testuuid'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/$', views.MegaTestDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

**testuuid/index.html**

```
{% if test_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for test in test_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'testuuid:detail' test.uuid %}">{{ test.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No tests available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I assume a damn simple mistake, but I really have no clue at this point.

The complete traceback can be found here http://dpaste.com/3JTB5NZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `get_object()` method instead of `get()`.

```
class MegaTestDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = MegaTest

    def get_object(self):
        try:
            megatest = MegaTest.objects.get(uuid=self.kwargs['uuid'])
            return megatest

        except MegaTest.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

You can also work with `get_queryset()` or even just specify `pk` field in url and don't write any method in the view class. Django will automatically query on your specified field in [`pk_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg)